# IBM Lift CLI - Load with error "A delimiter is not valid or is used more than once"

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

I try this load command in Lift CLI with target Db2 on Cloud:

```
lift load -f xxx700.csv -ts SCHEMA -tt xxx700 -pf lift-parm -fo user \
  -a replace -dd þ -df DD.MM.YYYY -fd 0x3B -tsf YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.FFFFFF
```

and get the message "A delimiter is not valid or is used more than once"

Before I "put" the CSV-file from a Windows-Client to the landing zone.
Why is the `-data-delimiter þ` (ANSI 0xFE) not valid ?

Comment: `þ` does _not_ look like 0xFE at all. Why don't you specify the hex code in `-dd`?

Comment: 0xFE is the ANSI hex code for þ (Thorn), so the same result

Comment: That depends on your code page. The Unicode character `U+00FE LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN` is `0xC3 0xBE` in UTF-8 and `0x00FE` in UTF-16.  Only in some  *ASCII* code pages such as "ISO/IEC 8859-15" it is `0xFE`.  So what the `lift` command will get sent will depend on your terminal code-page.  Therefore better to specify it in hex I suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem: With IBM lift only character below 0x80 are valid as data-delimiter